# File Upload to API is not working for concurrent user in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

In one of my scenario, i need to upload file to an API and execute the same in JMeter. With single user setup, this API execute correctly. But while trying to execute the same API with concurrent user, we are getting below exception. Looks like at same time multiple users are tying to upload the file. So i guess file is going into read only mode. 
Can anyone please let me know is my understanding is correct or not? And how i can handle concurrent user in this case. Is I need to put some sleep time or schedule time?

Exception: {"version":"1.0.0.0","statusCode":500,"error":{"message":"Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.","code":"ARM_E_UNKNOWN"}}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like DB concurrency conflict.

> The situation when another user has performed an operation that
>   conflicts with the current operation is known as concurrency conflict.

Try to give wait time or use multiple upload files.

Comment: Thanks Sunny...Any idea how i can give wait time in Jmeter??

Comment: You can use "Test Action" sampler to pause the thread/wait time and "constant timer". If you need random then check other "Timers" like "Gaussian Random Timer","Poisson Random Timer". Let me know if it helps and solves your issue.